# Use VRPanoramaView with camera view in background

Tags: android, 360-panorama

Is it possible to set camera view as VRPanoramaView background (I use a transparent 360 degrees image) to use as simple augmented reality?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to set the VrPanoramaView background transparent and placed it in front of the camera preview. That worked. The problem is, that in a transparent panorama picture transparency is always shown black instead of transparent. A GVR collaborator told me today, that transparency is beyond the design of the widgets. So it seems there is no solution to your idea.